# How to determine cycles with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Based on sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
Machine = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Machine)
```

This is mocking a machine being on and off. 0 means that it is off, and 1 means that it is on over that period of time. However, due to poor data the machine will say its off in the middle of an on cycle seen in the data. (1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1) The machine is really on during this whole period and the 0 is an error. Does anyone know of a easy way to calculate the total number of on cycles this would have while ignoring instances of bad data?

The sample code above has 3 on cycles and 4 off cycles. What would be the best way to calculate this while ignoring random data errors in a on cycle.

Comment: Is there a heuristic approach for determining when data is bad, or can you only tell by looking at it?

Comment: Yes this is just an example of my data, I know why the data is bad but cannot fix getting the bad results. So i just need a way that will determine the cycles and take into account some rows of bad data.

Comment: How many consecutive `0` or `1` can be considered as a valid trail (cycle)?

Comment: I think instead of putting the data into a DataFrame, you could simply iterate over the list and increase a counter when the number changes, given that there has been more than `n` instances of that digit in a row, where `n` is the number of sequential occurrences for the state to be valid.

Comment: More than 5 consectuive 1 values can be considered a valid cycle time, however there may be a 0 in those. So 1,1,0,1,1, is considered a cycle, i need a way to be able to ignore that 0.

Comment: Liam, wont that just count the 1s and 0s? I need that total cycle, not just the count.

Comment: @SeanK22 if you did it correctly, you could create logic that would only increase the counter if a digit appeared enough times in a sequence.

Comment: Yes that is what I am asking, I am new to Python so am unsure how to do that...

Comment: @SeanK22 no worries I get it, and it's an interesting and surprisingly challenging exercise in logic so I'm working through some approaches myself.

Comment: Yes i have been working on it for a couple hours and have gotten no luck, any approach would be super helpful!

Comment: I see a string of "1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1"  This is consider 1 on period, right ?  So how many zeros in between is still be considered on ?

Comment: Correct, 2 or less 0s can be considered on.

Comment: To elaborate on @EBDS's question, could that string have four consecutive zeroes in it and still not be considered to have switched states? It's only a sequence of five?

Comment: The number of conesectective on periods changes, for this example lets just say that if i 1 is shown that means tha on period began and then once there are 3 or more conesecutive 0s it is off.

Comment: @SeanK22 so any string of 5 1s with a single interval of 0 or 00 would be on ?  What about 000010010010010010000 ?   it's a string of 5 1 but with 00 embedded alternatively.  Pardon my asking, trying to find the pattern.

Comment: That would be considered off, the tricky part is that there is no real pattern. The data will have a bunch of conesctuvie 1s with only a few 0s in it

Comment: So generally, the data are 1s but when there are 000, 0000 or more 0s, it's considered off ?

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe not the best way, but you can build something like:

```
df['error_n-2'] = df['Machine'].eq(df.col1.shift(-2))
df['error_n-1'] = df['Machine'].eq(df.col1.shift(-1))
df['error_n+1'] = df['Machine'].eq(df.col1.shift(1))
df['error_n+2'] = df['Machine'].eq(df.col1.shift(2))


df['nb_diff'] =df['error_n-2']+df['error_n-1']+df['error_n+1']+df['error_n+2']

#apply a rule of 3 on 4
df['potential_error']=np.where(df['nb_diff']>=3,True,False)

#clean
df.drop(columns=['error_n-2','error_n-1','error_n+1','error_n+2','nb_diff'], inplace=True) 

#exclude potential error
df[df['potential_error']==False]
```

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT: This answer feels a bit better, still using the same regex approach:

```
import re

patt = re.compile(r'000+')
off_states = patt.findall(''.join([str(i) for i in machine])

for s in off_states:
     print(s)
```

Output:

```
> 000000
> 0000000
> 00000000
> 0000000
```

We can then split the machine on these off states, and count the number of resulting 'on' states:

```
on_states = patt.split(''.join([str(i) for i in machine])
```

Output:

```
> ['', '111110111', '1110011111111', '111011111111', '']

state_changes = len(matches) + len([i for in in on_states if i != '']))
```

This gives the desired total states of `7`, and we can subtract 1 if needed to get the number of changes.

---

## Original:

Ok, so this feels a little hack-ish, but in my testing on your sample data it works.

We use regex to find the occurrences of more than 2 sequential zeros (i.e. 'off' state), then divide that into the length of the overall list to find the number of state changes.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'[0]{3}')
machine = [str(i) for i in machine]
matches = len(patt.findall(''.join(machine))
print(len(machine) // matches)
```

This gives me `7`, which by my count is the correct number of state changes. If someone could help me with the reasoning of why this works, that would be great...it makes sense to me intuitively but I can't put it into words.